# Mi MessageBox se repite varias veces en mi condicion

Tags: c#, array, vb.net, aplicación-escritorio

Quiero realizar la función de copiar y pegar un archivo de una carpeta a otra, y agregue un checkbox del datagriew para poder escoger varios registros y no solo uno por uno, por eso cree como un arreglo, bueno como se muestra en el código, y me cumple toda la función, todo ok, el problema es que sale a cada rato el

> MessageBox.Show("Archivo Copiado Exitosamente en C:\FACTURAS.");

```
private void btnarchivos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        try
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow ite in dgfacturas.Rows)
            {

                DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)ite.Cells[0];
                if (chk.Value == chk.TrueValue)
                {

                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgfacturas.Rows)

                    {

                        if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[0].Value))

                        {

                            string numser = row.Cells["Serie"].Value.ToString();

                            string numdoc = row.Cells["Documento"].Value.ToString();

                            string rutaInicial = @"\\hpserver\DBSQL\EF\20501820025\" + cmbanio.SelectedItem + @"\1SINCRONO\FACTURA\FILE\20501820025-01-" + numser + "-" + numdoc + ".pdf";
                            string rutaInicial2 = @"\\hpserver\DBSQL\EF\20501820025\" + cmbanio.SelectedItem + @"\1SINCRONO\FACTURA\FILE\20501820025-01-" + numser + "-" + numdoc + ".xml";
                            string rutaFinal = @"C:\FACTURAS\" + lblcliente.Text + @"\20501820025-01-" + numser + "-" + numdoc + ".pdf";
                            string rutaFinal2 = @"C:\FACTURAS\" + lblcliente.Text + @"\20501820025-01-" + numser + "-" + numdoc + ".xml";
                            if (!(Directory.Exists(@"C:\FACTURAS\" + lblcliente.Text)))
                            {
                                Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\FACTURAS\" + lblcliente.Text);

                                MessageBox.Show("Carpeta Creada!!");
                            }
                            if (File.Exists(rutaInicial) && File.Exists(rutaInicial2))
                            {
                                File.Copy(rutaInicial, rutaFinal, true);
                                File.Copy(rutaInicial2, rutaFinal2, true);
                                // MessageBox.Show("Archivo Copiado Exitosamente en C:\\FACTURAS.");
                            }
                            // MessageBox.Show("Archivo Copiado Exitosamente en C:\\FACTURAS.");
                        }
                       // MessageBox.Show("Archivo Copiado Exitosamente en C:\\FACTURAS.");
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("Archivo Copiado Exitosamente en C:\\FACTURAS.");
                }
                else if (chk.Value == chk.FalseValue)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Por favor escoja una fila.");
                }
                dgfacturas.EndEdit();
            }
           
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Verificar los procesos."+ex);
        }
    }
```

Adjunto imagenes del proyecto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y porque esta adentro del foreach que recorre las filas.. por eso... sacalo de ahi y ponelo donde queres realmente...

Comment: ¿Por qué tienes dos `foreach` cuando (a mi entender) uno solo es suficiente?. Lo que está en tu código puede leerse algo así: Por cada elemento que está marcado (primer `foreach`) recorre todo el grid otra vez (segundo `foreach`) y si el elemento está marcado, copialo. El resultado es que cada archivo se copia tantas veces como la cantidad de archivos marcados.

Comment: Tienen razon pero cuando quite los foreach ya no copia lo seleccionado con el check, solo copia un archivo. Alguna idea por favor?

Comment: no tenes que quitar los foreach, si no que tenes que estructurar tu codigo para que se entienda lo que queres hacer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sole extrae del foreach tu msgbox y agrega una variable para verificar que se ejecuto ejemplo:

```
  bool estaCopiado=false;
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgfacturas.Rows)

   {

      ....
          
     estaCopiado= true;         
    }

if(estaCopiado == true)
{
 MessageBox.Show("Archivo Copiado Exitosamente en C:\\FACTURAS.");
}
```

Saludos

Comment: jajaja tienes razon, no es algo muy estructurado, pero soluciona mi problema, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no necesitas dos foreach, solo es importante organizar las instrucciones. Podría funcionar de la siguiente forma y te imprimiría por cada archivo seleccionado el mensaje de que se ha copiado. Podrias ponerlo fuera del foreach al finalizar para que solo se muestre una vez si son muchos archivos.

```
    private void btnarchivos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow ite in dgfacturas.Rows)
            {
                DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)ite.Cells[0];

                if (chk.Value == chk.TrueValue)
                {

                    string numser = ite.Cells["Serie"].Value.ToString();

                    string numdoc = ite.Cells["Documento"].Value.ToString();

                    string rutaInicial = @"\\hpserver\DBSQL\EF\20501820025\" + cmbanio.SelectedItem + @"\1SINCRONO\FACTURA\FILE\20501820025-01-" + numser + "-" + numdoc + ".pdf";
                    string rutaInicial2 = @"\\hpserver\DBSQL\EF\20501820025\" + cmbanio.SelectedItem + @"\1SINCRONO\FACTURA\FILE\20501820025-01-" + numser + "-" + numdoc + ".xml";
                    string rutaFinal = @"C:\FACTURAS\" + lblcliente.Text + @"\20501820025-01-" + numser + "-" + numdoc + ".pdf";
                    string rutaFinal2 = @"C:\FACTURAS\" + lblcliente.Text + @"\20501820025-01-" + numser + "-" + numdoc + ".xml";
                    if (!(Directory.Exists(@"C:\FACTURAS\" + lblcliente.Text)))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\FACTURAS\" + lblcliente.Text);

                        MessageBox.Show("Carpeta Creada!!");
                    }
                    if (File.Exists(rutaInicial) && File.Exists(rutaInicial2))
                    {
                        File.Copy(rutaInicial, rutaFinal, true);
                        File.Copy(rutaInicial2, rutaFinal2, true);
                        // Esto se imprime por cada archivo copiado
                        MessageBox.Show("Archivo Copiado Exitosamente en C:\\FACTURAS."); 
                    }
                        // MessageBox.Show("Archivo Copiado Exitosamente en C:\\FACTURAS.");
                    
                    // MessageBox.Show("Archivo Copiado Exitosamente en C:\\FACTURAS.");
                    
                    //MessageBox.Show("Archivo Copiado Exitosamente en C:\\FACTURAS.");
                }
                else if (chk.Value == chk.FalseValue)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Por favor escoja una fila.");
                }
                dgfacturas.EndEdit();
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Verificar los procesos." + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Este codigo va a mostrar el mensaje "Por favor escoja una fila" por cada fila no seleccionada, independientemente de si se selecciono alguna otra... Todo el codigo de origen estaba mal estructurado

Comment: Es correcto, supongo que sería mucho mejor que se habilite esta función solo cuando al menos se seleccione una fila y entonces si, se realice el procedimiento y al final muestre un solo mensaje de confirmación de copiado.

Comment: es correcto debo de pensar otra manera de estructurarlo, porque sigue saliendo, "Por favor escoja una fila" por cada fila no seleccionada. Muchas gracias por los comentarios igual.